# Difference between Date column in database vs Date in java

Tags: java, postgresql, datetime, database-design

I have to create a table in PostgreSQL. One of the column is `add_date` which should contain the current date at which the row was inserted.

I am confused between:

Whether should I create a column as `add_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE` and let database do the job of generating the date.

OR

I should declare the column as `VARCHAR` and pass current date using java.

What should be the best approach and Why should I go for one?

Thanks.

Comment: be careful. PostgreSQL stores only date in Date columns, not datetime, unlike Oracle. If u want to store datetime use timestamp type.

Comment: @AlexanderPrisadkov: every database except Oracle stores date values without a time in a `date` column.

Comment: @AlexanderPrisadkov The SQL standard defines the type `Date` as representing a date only, without time-of-day. To track a moment (a date, a time-of-day, and time zone or offset-from-UTC), the standard defines `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. To track a date with time but without a zone/offset (not a moment), the standard defines `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Postgres follows the standard in this matter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , @BasilBourque guys look at the tags:) `datetime` included.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name **not every** databases stores date values without a time in a date column. what about some dialects of Firebird or apache phoenix?

Comment: @AlexanderPrisadkov: [Quote from the Firebird manual](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-date) "*The DATE data type [...] stores only date without time*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name **The same link** : `Dialect 1 DATE data can be defined alternatively as TIMESTAMP and this is recommended for new definitions in Dialect 1 databases.` [Data Types for Dates and Times](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEVER** store date values in a VARCHAR column, just don't

The column should definitely be defined with the data type `DATE`. Whether or not you want to provide the value from Java is a different question.

But even if you correctly define it as

```
add_date DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
```

you can still pass a date from Java.

```java
String sql = "insert into the_table (some_column, add_date, other_column) values (?,?,?)"
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setInt(1, 42);
pstmt.setObject(2, LocalDate.now());
pstmt.setString(3, "Some String");
```

Comment: "NEVER store date values in a VARCHAR column, just don't"

Could you please shed some light on this as why we should never do this?
 I ask because the last developer who worked on the project is using as VARCHAR.

Comment: The most obvious example: it will allow you to store invalid dates or even values like `'last friday'` `'some day in the future'`  in such a column. It won't sort properly and you will have to convert it to proper date for even the most simple operations. And then you realize that the format isn't consistent and you get loads of errors when you try to convert that string back to a proper date. Believe me. Questions like "How can I convert a string to a date when the format changes for each row" are asked here probably once every week.